# Bouncycastle authorityKeyIdentifier

Tags: c#, ssl, cryptography, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I'm trying to create an SSL certificate, and in doing so I am seeing a browser warning: `Issuer_Unknown`.

To test, I made certificate with `makecert` especially signed for that domain, and the `authorityKeyIdentifier(oid = 2.5.29.1)` extension differs from mine generated with `BouncyCastle`, is that right?

My code:

```csharp
//Loading keyPair from PEM file.
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair LocalCertificate; 
var fs = new FileStream(myCertPath, FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr, new PemPassword());
LocalCertificate = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) pr.ReadObject();

//extend certificate 
var subjectKeyID = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(LocalCertificate.Public);
certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier, false, new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(subjectKeyID));
```

Comment: It seems that you are encountering two issues :
- An UNKNOWN_ISSUER issue : This one is due to the fact that your CA is not recognized by Firefox. Are you actually a CA or are you creating a self-signed certificate (I assume the latter but prefer to ask)
- You are comparing a certificate created with MaeCert and one with your BouncyCastle code and you are asking why they're different ?

Comment: @Frederic AuthorityKeyIdentifiers are different. I have same code on java, and it works fine, but that .net bouncycastle realization works bad.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the issue and question you are asking, can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @Frederic
1) I create key pair with "makecert";
2) Add .cer to Trusted Root Authorities
3) Create new certificate programically with BC, signed by that key pair, for example.com domain.
In doing so I had needed generated X509Certificate2 and try connect to client as server with that cert, and browser warning that mine certificate are invalid.